# How do I reset a git repo to a revision before a merge, and remerge the branch?

Tags: git

I have a repo on `myBranch` and merged the changes from `donorBranch` today. however, when resolving merge conflicts, things went bad several commits later down the line and I want to go back to the time before I merged from `donorBranch`. I identified commit `1` as the last time before I merged `donorBranch` so I did

```
git checkout 1 .
```

to get me back to that state.

However, when I tried `git merge donorBranch` again, I received the error

```
Already up to date.
```

How can I remerge `donorBranch`?

Comment: `git switch myBranch; git reset --hard 1` This assumes you're telling the truth about 1 being the last commit that was HEAD on myBranch just before the merge. You might not be.  It would be better to show us the log graph or the reflog so we can judge for ourselves.

Comment: `git checkout 1 .` just changes the state in the working directory and index, but does not reset the branch to a different commit. Since you did not change the commit history and `donorBranch` was already merged, you can't merge it again. You have to ditch all history since the merge and the merge itself and pretend they never happened. That's what @matt suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to go back to the time before I merged from `donorBranch`. I identified commit `1` as the last time before I merged `donorBranch`

Then say (assuming you are still on `mybranch`)

```
git reset --hard 1
```

This will indeed take you back in time as if the merge had never happened. You can then merge `donorBranch` afresh.

---

Do not be afraid, because all the commit states you've been in in `mybranch` are preserved in the reflog. Everything is undoable.

Also I recommend never saying `checkout`. It has been superseded by `switch` and `restore`.

Comment: Also note that both `switch` and `restore` are explicitly marked EXPERIMENTAL in the documentation.  I recommend never using `switch` and `restore`; stick with `checkout` and `cat-file`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell They've said that for ages. They've proved their worth and safety, over time.